# flutter_markdown multiple line breaks not working

Tags: flutter, dart, markdown

I am trying [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) package to markdown some content. But it is not working properly for multiple line breaks.

```
 String exampleData="\n\nLine 1. \n\nLine2.\n\n\n\n### Heading \n\nLine3";
 Markdown(data: exampleData,)
```

The output is [image]

I tried with line breaks "<br />" but it didn't worked

```
 String exampleData="Line 1. \n\nLine2. <br /> <br /> \n\n### Heading \n\nLine3";
```

Out put is [image]

Can someone help me with this line breaks or any alternative packages.

Comment: try `</br>` instead of `<br/>`. I'm not sure if that will help

Comment: @AdnanAlshami not working

Comment: try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/html

Comment: Ask the package creator, I've made a pull request a long time ago and he was very active at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a nasty trick (not a solution) that may be of help in this specific case. I don't recommend it, but couldn't find any other workaround using flutter_markdown so far, and I couldn't find any other package in substitution neither.

[image: Checkout the image]

You can take advantage of using triple apostrophes to add vertical space.

It is a nasty workaround, but couldn't find anything better so far to add vertical space.

Comment: But I don't have markedUp data. I have markdown code. https://guides.github.com/pdfs/markdown-cheatsheet-online.pdf

Answer (score 13):

check out below link!!

[enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/issues/40#issuecomment-380247270)

br tag is not working, so using 3 back slash + n instead of br tag

```
String exampleData="Line 1. \\\nLine2. \\\n## Heading \\\nLine3";
```

Answer (score 3):

A decent Work Around.

A new feature is added in [Flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) package called `paddingBuilders` , from version 0.6.8. you can add padding to all of the blocks available in markdown like below.

```
MarkdownBody(
  data: markDown,
  paddingBuilders: <String,
  MarkdownPaddingBuilder>{
    'p': PPaddingBuilder(),
    'h3': H3PaddingBuilder(),
  },
)
```

where you have to define the padding builder like below.

```
class PPaddingBuilder extends MarkdownPaddingBuilder {
  @override
  EdgeInsets getPadding() => const EdgeInsets.only(top: SGSpacing.xlarge);
}

class H3PaddingBuilder extends MarkdownPaddingBuilder {
  @override
  EdgeInsets getPadding() => const EdgeInsets.only(top: SGSpacing.xxlarge);
}
```

The list of all `blockTag` available in [Flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) from source code is below:

```
const List<String> _kBlockTags = <String>[
  'p',
  'h1',
  'h2',
  'h3',
  'h4',
  'h5',
  'h6',
  'li',
  'blockquote',
  'pre',
  'ol',
  'ul',
  'hr',
  'table',
  'thead',
  'tbody',
  'tr'
];
```

PS: padding will not work for inline Tags. only block Tag applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Just add ' \  u2028' for line breaks.
This is the Unicode Character 'LINE SEPARATOR'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<br>` with `\x03` like this. `\x03` is End of text(`ETX`) in ASCII:

```
text.replaceAll('<br>', '\x03');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found this package https://pub.dev/packages/markdown_widget

It's not a completely solution but this package support some tags os html like <\br>, in this case I added that tag in the markdown and works

Answer (score 1):

All the given solutions did not work for my use case. I have a text, where a new line is marked as \n. The problem occurs, if i want to insert \n\n.
I solved the issue as follows:

```
text.replaceAll('\n\n', '''
\n
\u200B 
\n
'''
);
```

This inserts a zero-width space which was sufficient for me to have two new lines.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, when use String single line, not use """ or ''', use \n with 2 space
Below code show same UI

> var _markdownSingleLine = 'Demo  \n  Break  \n  line';

> var _markdownMultiLine =
> '''
> Demo
> Break
> line
> ''';

[Demo break line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOF4x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to a [now deleted issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20200910202704/https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/issues/40), flutter_markdown supports explicit line breaks using a backslash at the end of the line. Using this syntax, your example would be:

```markdown
\
\
Line 1.\
\
Line2.\
\
\
\
### Heading
\
Line3
```